# Old javax libraries compatibility with jakarta

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I updated my java project with the latest Java JDK and Tomcat 10. The new libraries use jakarta and you need to rename all your javax. to jakarta...

The libraries included in gradle are:

```
compileOnly group: 'jakarta.servlet', name: 'jakarta.servlet-api', version: '5.0.0'
compileOnly group: 'jakarta.servlet.jsp', name: 'jakarta.servlet.jsp-api', version: '3.0.0'
compileOnly group: 'jakarta.el', name: 'jakarta.el-api', version: '4.0.0'
compileOnly group: 'jakarta.websocket', name: 'jakarta.websocket-api', version: '2.0.0'
compileOnly group: 'jakarta.security.enterprise', name: 'jakarta.security.enterprise-api', version: '2.0.0'
implementation group: 'jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl', name: 'jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api', version: '2.0.0'
implementation group: 'org.glassfish.web', name: 'jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl', version: '2.0.0'
```

But I found I couldnt use Sitemesh and Htmlcompressor libraries anymore because they use old javax. library. If I include javax. libraries:

```
compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'
```

I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError errors.

Is there a way to have compatibility with the old libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Include both the old and the new libraries? Since there are two different namespaces, they might be able to live together. If it works, it should be enough as a transitory solution before everybody migrates to jakarta.

Comment: I expect that won't work, because those libraries are likely used within the context of the greater Jakarta EE container, and thus must be able to call into, or be called by the implementations of the container, which will use the new API namespace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Right. In that case, take your accumulated leave and hope that the Jakarta transition wave has already swept over the Java world by the time you return from vacation. (https://xkcd.com/989/)